# How to do symmetric modeling on Houdini?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to switch to Houdini from XSI.

In XSI I could do something called *symmetric modeling*. Cut an object by half, and mirror it. And edit just the source half, then I get exactly same result on both sides automatically mirrored without any concern.

I tried to do this with Modify - Mirror, but it seems the mirrored object is disconnected from source object, so editing on source object won't be applied on the mirrored object automatically.

How can I make it to be applied automatically?

Answer (score 2):

See here. Full tutorial.

http://vimeo.com/34300829

Also here.

http://www.sidefx.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=1846&Itemid=351

1. mirror faces rather than an object.
2. select current editing node.
3. check template node if you want to see live preview of finally mirrored model.

I don't know yet how to see template node look shaded.

Answer (score -1):

on the mirror options, the consolidate distance set it to 0.01